# how to proceed on ajax request if coming result from php is false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making a form where I have one text box name "mobileNo" for search record from database php using ajax , If record found it prints `Record found`, If not found and when it say in php `echo "Record not found";` I want to do some javascript action for example I want to change the search button color or it's text from search to submit . How do I do that?

```
      $(document).ready(function(){                
      $('#btn').on('click', function() {    
      var mobile_no = $('#mobile_no').val(); 

        if (mobile_no != ""){           
        $.post('testPht.php', {mobile_no: mobile_no}, function(data){
        $('div#errorDiv').html(data);
        });            
        }else{      
        $('#errorDiv').html("field required");            
        }
        }); 
        });                 

    php

    if(isset($_POST['mobile_no']))  { $mobile_no = $_POST['mobile_no'];          
    search query
    echo  "Record Found"; }else{ echo "Record not Found"; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `.trim()` is just a suggest from another developper , you don't have to use it if you don't need it

```
$.post('testPht.php', {mobile_no: mobile_no}, function(data)
{
    if(data.trim() == "Record Found")
    {
        // do what you want if record is founded
    }
    else if(data.trim() == "Record not Found")
    {
        // do what you want if record not founded
    }
});
```

Comment: suggest trimming that data...php is notorious for adding whitespace to text

Comment: almost 5 years using PHP never got that probleme but maybe i will add it :D

Comment: probably don't ever use it to check absolute text values in ajax much though either. never an issue with json

Comment: @charlietfl sure :p :p